# $\lim_nf_n(x)=x_0$ implies $x\in\operatorname{cl}\left(\bigcup_nf_n^{-1}(x_0)\right)$ whenever $x_0$ belongs to the codomain

Tags: general-topology

Let $X,Y$ be topological spaces, $f_n:X\to Y$ sequence of continuous functions, and take a point $x\in X$.

Call $y_0:=\lim_nf_n(x)$ and suppose $y\in f_n(X)$ for all $n$.
Is it true that

$$
x\in\operatorname{cl}\left(\bigcup_nf_n^{-1}(x_0)\right)\;?
$$

Comment: Please avoid all-$\rm\LaTeX$ titles.

Comment: *After edit:* $f_n(x)=\frac1n\arctan x$, evaluated in $x=5$ (I don't want to mention the value in the codomain, because it is mentioned six times with three different names).

Answer (score 2):

Define $f_n : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $f_n(x) = \frac{1}{n}$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Then $f_n(1) = \frac{1}{n}$ tends to $0$. But for all $n$, $f_n^{-1}(0) = \emptyset$, so $$\operatorname{cl}\left(\bigcup_nf_n^{-1}(0)\right) = \emptyset$$